# how i i can transparent background on android studio?

Tags: android, layout, transparent, alpha

i want to design a layout exactly like image below.

when i put my linear layout alpha as transparent , all icons inside it also become transparent and its completely normal. but i want a way to just have transparent background not all items !

i want a transparent layout like this:

[image]

but my layout shows like this :

[image]

here is my code :

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:alpha="0.5"
    >



    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:alpha="1"
        >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="1dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.333"
            android:padding="10dp"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@mipmap/consert"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                />

        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="1dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.333"
            android:padding="10dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@mipmap/consert"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                />

        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="1dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.333"
            android:padding="10dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@mipmap/consert"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>



    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="1dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.333">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@mipmap/consert"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                />

        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="1dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.333">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@mipmap/consert"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                />

        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="1dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.333">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@mipmap/consert"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: make backgroud with transparent layout, and then in tranparent portion set your icons. and your result will make you happy

Comment: i think it is what i have done! can you tell me how i can fix it in my code ? tnx

Comment: On the top LinearLayout, just give it a transparent color to the background, say do a #FF000000 and this will prevent your layout widget from being affected by the alpha property.

Comment: @Saeid nope you have not done like that.

Comment: Side note: You are using unnecessary layouts. And layout nesting is bad for performances.

Comment: @Rotwang you mean relative layouts ? how can i fix it ? :) i want these photos be exactly just like abow photo (2 row and 3 colums ) and have margins.

Comment: There are MANY options. i.e.: using a GridView. Or using a single RelativeLayout as the root container and displace the children Views accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try like this if you want to adjust the transparent change the alpha in color I gave as #55000000 you can change the alpha value(55) whatever you want. if you wish black transparency you can use #55FFFFFF

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
              android:orientation="vertical"
    >


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:background="#55000000"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="3"
            >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="10dp"
                >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                    />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="10dp"
                >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                    />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="10dp"
                >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                    />

            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="3"
            >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="10dp"
                >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                    />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="10dp"
                >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                    />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:padding="10dp"
                >

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                    />

            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

for trasnparent

```
android:background="00000000";
```

black transparent (in your case)

```
android:background="55000000";
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to set transparency of any colour then you can click on that colour. Android studio show two lines 1 for changing colour and other for changing transparency so you can adjust transparency from there.

Answer (score 0):

This code for transparency also worked for me:

```
android:background="@null"
```

On the other hand, for black transparency (as others answered before)

```
android:background="55000000"
```